# How does p5.Vector.random2D() work under the hood?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, p5.js

How would I write the p5.js function `p5.Vector.random2D()` in pure vanilla JS? I'm trying to recreate it in regular canvas without using p5.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

code from github/p5.js

```
Vector.random2D = function random2D() {
  let angle = Math.random() * constants.TWO_PI;
  let length = 1;
  return {x: length * Math.cos(angle), y: length * Math.sin(angle)};
};
```